# Is it possible to have custom GROUP BY for MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have been trying to find the simplest way to group the two age groups in my query. Is it possible for something like this to work?

```
SELECT age,
sum(case when age < '20' then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when age > '20' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM Contact
GROUP BY ...."custom group one"......"custom group one".....??
```

I know you should group on a column usually, but in my case I that doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thx!

```
Table:            Desired Query Result:
Name    Age       0           1
John    18        Under 20    2
Harry   22        Over 20     2
Mary    17
Megan   27
```

---

### SOLVED:

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN age = '21' THEN 'young'
  WHEN  age BETWEEN '22' AND '60' THEN 'middle'                          
  ELSE 'old'
END, Count(id)
FROM  Contact
GROUP BY CASE
  WHEN age = '21' THEN 'young'
  WHEN  age BETWEEN '22' AND '60' THEN 'middle'                       
  ELSE 'old'
END
```

Note: `AS` can be used to assign alias to grouping conditions in `SELECT` statement and hence avoid repeating conditions twice, i.e.

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN age = '21' THEN 'young'
  WHEN  age BETWEEN '22' AND '60' THEN 'middle'                          
  ELSE 'old'
END AS age_range, Count(id)
FROM  Contact
GROUP BY age_range
```

Comment: Please, post sample of your data together with table structure and also desired result

Comment: Thx Alma Do. I updated my original post.

Comment: @user1218172 Please create an answer and mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

So that will be:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(1), 
  age>20 AS Above20 
FROM t 
GROUP BY age>20
```

-check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19fef/2).

Or, alternatively, with `SUM()` and with column view:

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(age>20, 1, 0)) AS Above20,
  SUM(IF(age<=20, 1, 0)) AS Below20
FROM 
  t
```

-check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19fef/3).

Comment: Thank you. If I wanted to create further groups by defining a third or forth age group, how would I modify this query...sorry...I should have put three or four groups in my example.

Comment: Yes, you should show full sample. Otherwise answers may be not so precise as you wish